# Prove that $x^x+y^y=z^z$ doesn't have integer solutions

Tags: number-theory, proof-verification, contest-math, exponentiation, integers

Prove that $x^x+y^y=z^z$ doesn't have integer solutions

To be honest, I don't see any way to start this problem, I tried for hours but it's not as easy as I thought.

Any hints?

As you can see in the comments, there is a solution for natural numbers, the problem is when the set is extended to integers solutions.

*This is a problem for a national olympiad in my country, this olympiad usually puts all the solutions but i didn't found a solution for this problem in the page, i don't know why.

**Possible answer:**

*Property:*

Be $A,B,C$ $\in \Bbb R$ $\ne 0$ such that $A+B=C$. Then exist $U,V \in {A,B,C}$ such that:  $$2|U| \gt 2|V| \ge |U|$$

**Proof:** Write $C'=-C$, then $A+B+C'=0$. The numbers $A,B,C \ne 0$ by hypothesis, and they can't be the three of the same sign because then they can't add $0$, so there are two of the numbers $A, B, C'$ that have the same sign and the other has a different sign.

Amplifying the equality $A+B+C'= 0$ $\,$ by $-1$ if its necessary, we can assume that there are two of them (which we will call $X,Y$) that are positive and the third negative (we will call it $-Z$, with $Z\gt 0$). Then we have $Z=X+Y$ with $X,Y,Z \gt 0$ and that $X,Y,Z$ are equal to $|A|, |B| , |C|$ in some order.

WLOG we can assume that $X\le Y$ , then:

$$Z=X+Y\le 2Y \lt 2Y+2X = 2Z$$

Obtaining $2Z \gt 2Y \ge Z$ as we wanted.

**Solution:** Assume that  $$(1): \; x^x+y^y=z^z$$

has integer solutions $\ne 0$, let $(x,y,z) = (a,b,c)$. According to the property, there exists integers $\ne 0$ $(u,v) \in (a,b,c)$ such that $2|u^u| \gt 2|v^v| \ge |u^u|$. Dividing by 2 and taking $\log$ we see that there are non-zero integers $(u,v)$ such that: $$u\log |u| \gt v\log |v| \ge u\log |u| - \log 2$$
That can be written as: $$(2): \;0 \lt u\log |u| - v\log |v| \le \log 2$$

The inequality (2) says that $u\log|u| \gt 0$ or $v\log|v| \lt 0$, but if $v \log |v| \lt 0$ then: $$u \log |u| - v \log |v| = (-v)\log|-v|\;-\;(-u)\log |-u|$$ with $(-v)\log|-v| \gt 0$, so unless we make a substitution, we can assume that $u \log |u| \gt 0$. In this case, necessarily $u \ge 2$, so 
 the second inequality of (2) says that: $$v \log |v| \ge u \log |u| - \log 2 \ge 2 \log 2 - \log 2 \gt 0$$

Matching this with the first equality of (2) we get: $$ log 2 \ge u \log |u| - v \log |v| \gt (v+1)\log |v| - v\log|v| = \log|v| \ge \log2$$ a contradiction. Thus $x^x+y^y=z^z$ doesn't have any integers solution.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72988/discussion-on-question-by-rodrigo-pizarro-prove-that-xxyyzz-doesnt-have).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Note that the other solutions don't deal with the case of negative integers.)

$0^0$ is undefined, so work with these being non-zero. If you believe that $0^0 = 0$ or $1$, that can be easily dealt with, and is left as an exercise to the reader.

We consider cases based on how many of them are positive or negative.

---

If all of the integers are positive, WLOG $ x \leq y < z$

Show that for $n \geq 1$, $(n+1)^{n+1} > (n+1) n^n \geq 2 n^n$.

Hence $x^x + y^y \leq 2 y^y  < (y+1)^{y+1} \leq z^z$, so there are no solutions.

---

If one of the integers is negative, it cannot be $z$. WLOG let $ x < 0$.
If $x = -1$, clearly there are no solutions.
If $ x < -1$, the the LHS is not an integer, but the RHS is. Hence, no solutions.

---

If exactly 2 of the integers are negative, then those values of $ |n^n| \leq 1$. The remaining value of $n^n$ from the positive integer is either 1 or $ \geq 4$.
Thus, the only possibility for solutions is $\pm x^x \pm y^y = \pm1$.
If $x = -1$ or $ y = -1$, clearly there are no solutions.
Otherwise, $x, y \leq -2$ and $|n^n| \leq \frac{1}{4}$, and thus this has no solutions.

---

If all 3 of the integers are negative, if 2 of them are equal, then the third raised to itself is 0, hence no solutions. So all of them are distinct. WLOG, $ x < y < 0$.

If any of them are $-1$, then we can easily rule out solutions (like the previous cases).

Then, for $ n \leq -2$,  $\frac{|n^n|} { |(n-1)^{n-1}|} \geq 3 > 2$ in a manner similar to the all-positive case.
As such, we have no solutions to $\pm |x^x| \pm |y^y| = \pm |z^z|$.

Thus, there are no solutions to $x^x + y^y + z^z = 0 $.

Answer (score 8):

A proof for positive integers.

Suppose $x$ and $y$ are positive integers with $x\le y$.
Then $x^x+y^y<2y^y$.  We can show that 
$$ x^x+y^y \le 2y^y < (y+1)^{y+1}. $$
Consider $$f(y) = (y+1)\log(y+1)-y \log y - \log 2.$$
Note $f(1)>0$ and 
$$f'(y) = \log(y+1)  -\log y > 0$$ for all $y>0$.
Hence, $f(y)>0$ for all $y>0$ and so
$$2y^y < (y+1)^{y+1}$$ for all $y>0$. Thus $x^x+y^y<(y+1)^{y+1}$ and so $x^x+y^y=z^z$ has no solutions in positive integers.

Answer (score 1):

This is a proof for positive integers. Obviously, $z> x,y$ and furthermore $x\neq y.$ If not, then $2 = \dfrac{z^z}{x^x}\geq\dfrac{(x+1)^{x+1}}{x^x} >x+1$, so $x=1.$ But then $z^z = 2$ has no integer solution. Therefore, assume $x<y<z$ or $z = x+m+n$, $y = x+m$ with $n,m\geq1.$ Then we have the equation:

$$1 = \left(\dfrac{x}{x+m+n}\right)^{x}\dfrac{1}{(x+m+n)^{m+n}}+\left(\dfrac{x+m}{x+m+n}\right)^{x+m}\dfrac{1}{(x+m+n)^{n}}.$$
Now notice, that $f(a) = \dfrac{a^a}{(a+t)^a} = \dfrac{1}{(1+\frac{t}{a})^a}$ is decreasing in $a$ converging to $e^{-t}.$ In particular, $f(a)\leq f(1)=\dfrac{1}{t+1}.$ Wit this and the obvious bound $x,n,m\geq 1,$ it follows that: 
$$1\leq \dfrac{1}{1+m+n}\cdot \dfrac{1}{9}+\dfrac{4}{(2+n)^2}\cdot \dfrac{1}{3}\leq \dfrac{1}{3}\cdot\dfrac{1}{9}+\dfrac{4}{9}\cdot\dfrac{1}{3} = \dfrac{4}{27},$$

a contradiction.